# Is angle always formed between rays?

Tags: terminology, definition, angle

From the standard definition, I read from textbooks, the angle is formed between two **rays** with a common vertex.

But is it false that angle can be formed between two **line segments**?

Comment: Two intersecting line segments typically make 4 angles in two pairs of angles with equal measure. Context sometimes determines which angle you care most about.

Comment: @MarkS. So do you mean that angles can be formed by line segments also!

Comment: A line segement can be infinitely extended, it is the second postulate.

Comment: @DougM yeah, but what about interior and exterior of the angle? Is it the same for the angle between line segments as well as the angle between rays (of extended line segments)?

Comment: If two segements intersect, then you will get 4 angles.  These are pairs of vertical angles.      Angles will either be suplimentary or congruent (exept in the bastard case of 4 right angles).  If the segements do not intersect, then they can be extended until they do (unless they are paralell).  Or you are working in higher dimensions, or non-Euclidean spaces, where lines can be non-parallel and non-intsecting.